Delegatecall failing 'could not coalesce error'
I'm trying to set a message to my Contract setmsg through a proxy contract using delegatecall.Using hardhat.
getting this error:
  error: {
    code: -32603,
    message: "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'delegate failed'",
    data: {
      message: "Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'delegate failed'",
      txHash: '0x61cbb5af804b22f21431f6e577db17bc677ee595af1f509bf769dfa63c8d5d2a',
      data: '0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f64656c6567617465206661696c65640000000000000000000000000000000000'
    }
  },
  payload: {
    method: 'eth_sendRawTransaction',
    params: [
      '0x02f8f5827a6982029d843b9aca0085010f68944a830927c09493b800cd7acdca13754624d4b1a2760a86be0d1f0ab884c0ed254b000000000000000000000000bd2fe040d03eb1d1e5a151fbcc19a033332230190000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000040000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a6d65737361676573657400000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c001a08f5f604aac553f6552189763af2d6c5d06c6dc1a9509d68e68fa29ef0c7021e6a023883eb83df0b38d207d7e8b1f3a0f524d5de7200520b4b973844842b5f3363b'
    ],
    id: 9,
    jsonrpc: '2.0'
  },
  shortMessage: 'could not coalesce error'

Contract to set the message 

  pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract setmsg{
constructor (){

}
string public message = "no message";

function setmessage ( string calldata  _msg ) external payable{

    message =_msg;



}

function viewvalue ()public view returns(string memory mensaje){
mensaje=message;

}


} 

Proxy contract
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract proxymsg{

constructor (){

}

function setproxy (address _original, string calldata _msg ) external payable{

 (bool success, bytes memory data) =_original.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setmessage(string calldata)", _msg));

    require (success, "delegate failed");



}

}


js script to send transaction (hardcoded contract addresses)
async function main() {
    const provider = new hre.ethers.getDefaultProvider("http://localhost:8545/");
    const signer = new hre.ethers.Wallet("0xac0974bec39a17e36ba4a6b4d238ff944bacb478cbed5efcae784d7bf4f2ff80", provider);

      const msj = new hre.ethers.Contract("0x93B800CD7ACdcA13754624D4B1A2760A86bE0D1f", abi4, signer);
      const origin = new hre.ethers.Contract("0xBD2fe040D03EB1d1E5A151fbcc19A03333223019", abi3, signer);

      
      
      balance = await msj.setproxy("0xBD2fe040D03EB1d1E5A151fbcc19A03333223019","messageset", {value: 10, gasLimit: 600000});
      console.log(balance);
  
     
     
      console.log(changed);
      balance2 = await origin.viewvalue();
      console.log(balance2);
      
  } 
  
  
  main().catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exitCode = 1;
  });



You don't have to pass calldata in the argument while encoding the function signature of setmessage. Just remove calldata, it would work fine:
(bool success, bytes memory data) = _original.delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSignature("setmessage(string)", _msg));

